# pdo drivers shows no value in linux

Tags: linux, pdo

[this is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57iDc.png)  i have install php5.6 with the following command:
  - sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
   and also install the php cli with this command : sudo apt-get install php5-cli.

then,

I have added following line to php.ini file for extenstion:
extension=pdo.so and extension=pdo_mysql.so

and given the extension path : 
extension = /usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_mysql.so

and use command : sudo apt-get install php-mysql

but still shows the pdo drivers no value when running phpinfo()

so, how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Try for php5 explicitely:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```